# TYPO3: Powermail - Show submitted info on redirect page

Tags: typo3, powermail

When the user submits a Powermail form how do you show the information that was entered on the redirected page?

By default it will reload the current page to show the entered info in place of the form. Because my form is in a popup modal I need to redirect to another page and show the submitted info there. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you redirect the powermail submit, you can't show the values again. Showing values is only possible without a redirect.

Comment: So, if my only option is to reopen the popup modal after submit to show the info, what would be the best way, on load, to check if the form was just submitted? I could check if the .powermail_create div exists, but is there a better way than that?

Comment: Just check if the GET or POST value tx_powermail_pi1[action]=create is set